# Is there any way of upgrading OSGeoLive from OSGeoLive 13 to OSGeoLive 14?

Tags: osgeo-live

I'm running OSGeoLive 13 inside a Virtual Box machine currently... I'd like to upgrade it from OSGeoLive 13 to OSGeoLive 14, but only upgrading its Ubuntu 18.04 to Ubuntu 20.04 won't solve this issue. I know I could create a new different virtual machine installing OSGeoLive 14 but I'd like to avoid this procedure if possible.

On the [OSGeoLive documentation](https://live.osgeo.org/en/index.html) I don't see anything related to upgrading it. Is it possible to do it in a reliable way? Or creating a new virtual machine installing it again would be a better idea?

Comment: Try upgrading to 20.04 then updating `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` with https://github.com/OSGeo/OSGeoLive/tree/master/sources.list.d